# Shell_exec PHP указать урл на файл make_license

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

У меня на хостинге доступна функция shell_exec. Когда сайт находился на своем сервере файл make_license копировал в /usr/bin/ и в php файле прописывал

```
$eee = shell_exec("make_license ".$p);
```

Сейчас файл находится на хостинге в корне сайта. Как правильно указать путь к файлу make_license?

Comment: Решил свою проблему. Вопрос решен, решение вот такое

$eee = shell_exec("cd /var/www/login/data/www/site.ru/engine && ./make_license ".$p);

Answer (score 1):

```
$directory = '/var/www/login/data/www/site.ru/engine';
$command = sprintf('%s/make_license %s', $directory, $p);
shell_exec($command);
```

rule of thumb - использовать абсолютные пути, даже если все валяется в каком-нибудь привычном `/usr/local/bin`. Ну и утилитарные исполняемые файлы приложения должны лежать вместе с приложением, если нужно обеспечить пользовательский доступ к ним - симлинк в тот же `/usr/local/bin`.